# Sorted doubly linked list and inserting values

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to make a sorted doubly-linked list with a function inserer() to insert values into it.

I write the whole program as follows :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct bi{
    int val;
    struct bi *prec;
    struct bi *suiv;
}bil;

void inserer (int v, bil *tete)
{
    bil *cour, *elt;

    cour = tete->suiv;

    while (cour != tete && cour->val < v)
        cour = cour->suiv;
    elt = (bil*) malloc(sizeof(bil));
    if (elt)
    {
        elt->val = v;

        (cour->prec)->suiv = elt;
        elt->suiv = cour;
        elt->prec = cour->prec;
        cour->prec = elt;
    }
}

int main()
{
    bil* tete;

    /*Creation tete fictif*/
    tete = (bil*) malloc (sizeof(bil));


    tete->prec = tete;
    tete->prec = tete;

    inserer (3,tete);
    return 0;
}
```

Then I try to use the function and insert a value (3 in the example)
with `inserer (3,tete);` But it keeps giving segmentation fault. 
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tete->suiv` is used uninitialized in

```
cour = tete->suiv;
```

Change

```
tete->prec = tete;
tete->prec = tete;
```

to

```
tete->prec = tete;
tete->suiv = tete;
```

Comment: You're awesome, How didn't I see that. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are getting segmentation fault because of `cour = tete->suiv;`

Initially both the pointer should be assigned to `tete`

```
cour->suiv = tete;
cour->suiv = tete;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set `tete->suiv` to anything. In `main` you probably meant

```
tete->prec = tete;
tete->suiv = tete;
```